# Preload изображений

Tags: jquery, изображения, javascript, html

Создавая свой сайт, я столкнулся с такой проблемой:

У меня имеется маленькое изображение, в одном из атрибутов которого есть ссылка на большое.

С загрузкой страницы загружать картинки нельзя, т.к. ссылки на картинки приходят ajax'ом.

При щелчке на маленькое у меня появляется большое, но, оно сначала отображается, а потом загружается, из-за чего создается дерганье.

Я думаю задача ясна:

Я хочу, чтобы после клика на маленькую картинку выполнялась какая то функция, и после загрузки большого изображение также выполнялась функция (другая)

Заранее благодарен

Порылся в нете, ничего толком не нашел

```
$('<div class="alert-wrapper"><div class="alert-shadow"></div><div class="pictures-box"></div></div>').appendTo('body');

var box = $('div.pictures-box').hide();

var inner = '<div class="alert-box-header alert-blue">Обзор изображений</div><div class="pictures-container"><table><tr><td><img/></td><td><img/></td><td><img/></td></tr></table><div class="alert-box-input"><input type="button" value="OK" /></div></div>';

shadow.css({opacity: 0.1}).fadeIn(300);
box.html(inner);
var imgs=$('div.pictures-container img');
if (data.photo1) {imgs[0].src='/images/big_images/'+data.photo1;} else imgs.eq(0).remove();
if (data.photo2) {imgs[1].src='/images/big_images/'+data.photo2;} else imgs.eq(1).remove();
if (data.photo3) {imgs[2].src='/images/big_images/'+data.photo3;} else imgs.eq(2).remove();                     box.fadeIn(300);
```

Comment: Покажите код, который подгружает картинку.

Comment: Дак он и не подгружает, он просто вставляет ее в страницу

Comment: В любом случае приведите код... Иначе пойду себя испитывать на передаче "Битва экстрасенсов"

Comment: ну вот, примерно так

Comment: она сюда добавляет пока большие изображения, а потом с помощью jquery увеличивает их.

Но вопрос ведь понятен, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы срабатывала функция после загрузки ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ (одного). А все остальное меня не особо волнует

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вот так.](http://jsfiddle.net/yrxzt/5/) created by [@caravaneer](/users/4402/caravaneer)

Answer (score 3):

Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/yrxzt/2/). После загрузки картинки вызывается alert.

Comment: А  как сделать так, чтобы она загрузилась на фоне, а потом отобразилась?